# Deeplink parameters for Google Assistant

Tags: ios, deep-linking, google-assistant-sdk, android-deep-link

When I have used deep-linking on past applications, the parameters that are available are well-documented. However, that has not been my experience with the Google Assistant app.

I need to be able to pre-fill and (ideally) automatically pass some prewritten text to the Google Assistant using the deep-link that it will search (invoke) immediately.

In my iOS/Android app, the user will write something: "What's the weather like today"? I can invoke the deep-link to Google Assistant easily via `googleassistant://` but do not know how to pass parameters to this link. Maybe it's not even possible, but perhaps someone knows how.

Ideally: `googleassistant://query=whats+the+weather+like&invoke=true`

Comment: There is so such deep link parameter for the Google Assistant.

Comment: Bummer, but thanks for letting me know @NickFelker! I don't need to necessarily follow this paradigm of deep-linking, but is this outcome possible in any other way you know of?

Comment: Right now, there's no way to do that programmatically to my knowledge aside from using the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview) which may do a lot of what you want.